# Qt: Is it thread-safe to copy an instance of an implicitly shared classes?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, thread-safety

The [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-modules.html#threads-and-implicitly-shared-classes) states:

> Beginning with Qt 4, implicit shared classes can safely be copied across threads, like any other value classes.

Thus, `getText()` from the below example will be thread-safe. Correct?

```
class MyClass {

private:
    QString text;

public:
    QString getText() const { return text; }      // Is this thread-safe?
};
```

Comment: If function is const and it performs only reads, like in your case - it mean thread-safe from the Standard Library point of view (C++11). However note that compiler doesn't verify it for you.

Comment: Yes because the cow mechanism employs atomics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your class is written it is thread safe.  No one can write to `text` so you can't have any synchronization issues.

If you had instead

```
class MyClass {

private:
    QString text;

public:
    QString getText() const { return text; }
    void setText(const QString& str) { text = str; }
};
```

Then the `getText` function is still safe as it doesn't change any state in the class but now the class itself is not thread safe.  Since you could set the state (write) in one thread you would need synchronization.

Comment: Well I assumed that even in your example the getter would still be thread-safe, since Qt guarantees that implicitly shared classes like QString "can safely be copied across threads".

Comment: @emkey08 It is.  I even say it: *Then the `getText` function is still safe*

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Thanks :-)

Comment: @emkey08 No problem.

Answer (score 3):

This topic is more complicated than it seems.

First, let's start with the definitions. An implicitly shared class is *reentrant* and *not* necessarily thread-safe. Reentrant means it's safe to concurrently access different instances of a class, and it's not necessarily safe to access a single instance, even if the access is read-only.

If every thread has its own copy of the same string, then they are free to do anything (read or write), whether the string is actually shared or not. This is safe because `QString` is reentrant. But in your case, you actually have several threads accessing a single instance to make a copy of it. That's not really reentrance, that's thread safety.

Copying is a read-only access. And it's here that the phrase “implicit shared classes can safely be copied across threads” becomes rather confusing.

If all access to a single instance is strictly read-only, then normal concurrency rules apply. That is, the object should be correctly published by some thread before it can be safely read by other threads. I'm not a great expert on C++ concurrency, but from my Java experience, correct publishing is more complicated than it seems, given various reordering, caching and optimization issues. To be safe, make sure that the `text` field is initialized before any of the reading threads start (not counting the initializing thread, of course) or use explicit synchronization at some point before the first read.

If two or more threads try to concurrently modify the instance, then, of course, it's not safe at all.

The most intriguing case if only one thread modifies its own copy. At first glance, it seems like it should be safe. Well, it is, in most cases, but only if modification happens *after* the copy was created. Consider the following example:

```
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QSemaphore>
#include <QString>
#include <QThread>

struct SourceThread : public QThread {
    QSemaphore &c;
    QString s = "0123456789ABCDEF0";
    SourceThread(QSemaphore &c) : c(c) {}
    void run() override {
        c.acquire();
        s[0] = 'x'; // concurrent access here
    }
};

struct DestinationThread : public QThread {
    QSemaphore &c;
    SourceThread &s;
    DestinationThread(QSemaphore &c, SourceThread &s) : c(c), s(s) {}
    void run() override {
        c.acquire();
        const QString copy = s.s; // and here
        QChar c1 = copy.at(0);
        QChar c2 = copy.at(0);
        if (c1 != c2)
            qDebug() << c1 << c2;
    }
};

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        QSemaphore c(2);
        SourceThread s(c);
        DestinationThread d(c, s);
        c.acquire(2);
        s.start();
        d.start();
        c.release(2);
        s.wait();
        d.wait();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

One would expect this example to be safe, and both `c1` and `c2` to be equal to either `'0'` or `'x'`, depending on whether the copy was taken before or after the modification. But if you're a concurrency expert, then the very words “before” and “after” should scream “Race condition!” to you. Indeed, given enough CPU cores, disabled optimizations and a few tries, this code sometimes print `'0' 'x'`, even though `copy` is even declared `const`! What happens behind the scene is this:

1. `SourceThread` (ST) checks reference count. It is equal to 1, so it proceeds without detaching.
2. `DestinationThread` (DT) creates a copy, bumping the reference count to 2. ST no longer cares, though.
3. DT takes the first char (`'0'`).
4. ST changes the first char to `'x'`.
5. DT takes the first char again, which is `'x'` this time.
6. Oops!

When I first came up with this example, I even thought that implicitly shared classes are not really reentrant. That's not true. The code above relies on thread safety, not on reentrance. A single instance is being accessed concurrently, although only one access is for writing and the other is for reading, it's still not safe.

So even though the docs say that “implicit shared classes can safely be copied across threads”, they can only be safely copied across threads if they are indeed copied *safely*. After the copy is created by some thread, it's free to modify it—no other thread will ever see those modifications. But concurrent read/write from different threads is a no-no.

Comment: "After the copy is created by some thread, it's free to modify it." -- Thus, if an implicitly shared value is **only** accessed via getter and setter functions, then getting and setting the value itself must be thread-safe, since the getter and setter will always copy the value before any assignment happens. Do you agree?

Comment: @emkey08, according to the docs, it's not guaranteed because, strictly speaking, it's concurrent access to a single instance: on thread assigns a new value, the other is making a copy of it at the same time. But looking at the code, I can't think of any way it could go wrong. It's just a pointer assignment. Moreover, reference counting uses ordered memory semantics, so I'd even assume that the reading thread will see the updated version as soon ad it's assigned.

Comment: @emkey, one more thing: even though `QString` assignment is “just” a pointer assignment, it's worth to note that it doesn't do anything “thready” *after* performing the assignment. It only increases the ref count *before*. It means that, in theory, the reading thread can never actually see the update. Or at least it could be one update late because ref count bump on the the next update will create a necessary memory barrier.

Comment: what if you added `copy.detach()` immediately after assigning to `copy`?

Comment: this scenario would get a lot more serious if instead of changing the first char of `s` SourceThread was deleting QString `s`. Then DT would be left with a dangling reference to an invalid shared memory space and crash could result.