# Is copying a const QString thread safe?

Tags: c++, qt, thread-safety, qstring

Code:

```
class Data {
    const QString qs; // const here is the point of the question
public:
    Data(const QString &s) : qs(s) {}
    QString getter() const { return qs; } // mutex needed?
    const QString &rgetter() const { return qs; } // not thread-safe at all?
}
```

The getter methods are called from multiple threads for same `Data` object, un-synchronized.

Now [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads-reentrancy.html#notes-on-qt-classes) says, emphasis mine:

> You can safely access different instances of QString from multiple threads simultaneously, but ***you can't safely access the same instance of QString from multiple threads simultaneously*** (unless you protect the accesses yourself with a QMutex).

However, in general in C++, when just reading `const` objects from multiple threads, mutex is not needed. There's the Copy-on-Write mechanism in the background after all, so does taking a copy of a `const QString` constitute the kind of access that is forbidden by the Qt doc quote above?

**Does `getter()` method above need a mutex to return a copy of `qs`, and is the `const` reference returned by `rgetter()` never really safe in multi-threaded context?**

---

If above code is broken for multi-threading, would this be a safe alternative?

```
class Data {
    const std::string ss; // will contain UTF-8
public:
    Data(const QString &s) : ss(s.toStdString()) {}
    QString getter() const { return QString::fromStdString(ss); }
}
```

Comment: It should be fine. As long as no one modifies the `QString` (which is enforced by the constness you applied), concurrent reads does not require to be synchronized.

Comment: Possibly related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072060/qt-is-it-thread-safe-to-copy-an-instance-of-an-implicitly-shared-classes).

Comment: Do you modify this instance elsewhere? Or do you just copy it?

Comment: @G.M. That is definitely a duplicate

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Maybe dupe, but not necessarily. QString has CoW mechanism, even if it is a const QString.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili It's const data memeber.

Answer (score 1):

In your sample, your member variable is `const`, that means you are guaranteed it is not mutated anywhere. Considering that, you can hand people const references to this variable or copies, and both are thread-safe.

```
class Data {
    const QString qs;

public:
    Data(const QString &s) : qs(s) {}
    QString getter() const { return qs; } // Safe, no life-time management needed
    const QString &rgetter() const { return qs; } // Safe, but you must make sure Data outlives the references.
}
```

Comment: Const class may have const pointers to non-const data outside the class. `const` only quarantees the `sizeof(qs)` bytes of data at `&qs` memory address should be get changed (barring `mutable` but I don't think QString has mutables).

Comment: @hyde The only thing that changes in the original buffer while copying is the 'reference count' and that count is an atomic integer, so it can be safely increased/decreased across threads. Otherwise you couldn't even destructors would need synchronization which is not reasonable.